# show current speed from gps coordinates

Tags: javascript, performance, math, gps, latitude-longitude

hi guys I'm developing a script to show the current speed in a platform that have its own function , but i get  always 0 for the current speed and the first longitude and latitude are the same as the second one, can someone help me please to get what's wrong and see if the algorithm is right

```
function save1() {
  js.saveData("value1", js.call('api.location.getLatitude()', {}));
  js.saveData("value2", js.call('api.location.getLongitude()', {}));
}

function save2(){
  js.saveData("value3", js.call('api.location.getLatitude()', {}));
  js.saveData("value4", js.call('api.location.getLongitude()', {}));
}
function repeate2() {

  js.callRepeatedly("save1()", 1000);
  js.callRepeatedly("save2()", 2000);
}

function setintext() {
  save1();
  save2();
  repeate2();
  //js.alert("geted");
  var lat1 = js.getData("value1");
  var long1 = js.getData("value2");
  var lat2 = js.getData("value3");
  var long2 = js.getData("value4");
  js.setProperty('Home.Text_1', 'text', lat1);
  js.setProperty('Home.Text_2', 'text', long1);
  js.setProperty('Home.Text_3', 'text', lat2);
  js.setProperty('Home.Text_4', 'text', long2);
}


function distance(lat1, long1, lat2, long2) {
  setintext();
  var R = 6371; // km (change this constant to get miles)
  var dLat = (lat2 - lat1) * Math.PI / 180;
  var dLon = (long2 - long1) * Math.PI / 180;
  var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
    Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI / 180) *
    Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
  var d = R * c;
  var dist = 0;
  dist = Math.round(d);
  var vitesse = dist / 3600000;
  js.setProperty('Home.Text_x', 'text', vitesse + "km/h");
}
```

Comment: Since you save to local storage both sets (lat/long) of coordinates at the same moment in setintext()... Isn't it is logic that the values are the same? I think you should store set1... and wait for a moment to save the second set. Also Think about transmission delay! I don't know where the data comes from... But is it really "real time" ?

Comment: You're getting the values one right after the other without changing location. Try changing the location between `save1()` and `save2()`

Comment: Louys Patrice Bessette
yeah i'm seting them in the same time 
but the save1() should be executed every 1 sec 
and save2() should be executed every 2 sec 
am i right ?
yeah real time exact coordinates

Comment: Eli Sadoff i'm testing it in a car with a high speed but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

What is your framework? Many JavaScript environments perform many IO-based and/or CPU-heavy operations asynchroneously, so polling for the position would not trigger a new computation, but would simply return the most recently computed position.

Can you have that framework call your code when it has computed a new position, instead of polling for the new position? It might well be that the framework has a new position e.g. only every three seconds, which means that the position in two subsequent seconds would be the same 2/3 of the time.

Of course, since you are saving to one set of position variables every second and to the other every two seconds, and starting both timers at the same time, you can expect to get the same position on half the runs anyway. Unless you rely on the GPS computation to occur synchroneously and taking considerable time, which is not an assumption I'd build upon.